# Does OpenSSH no longer support the "PermitRootLogin" keyword?

Tags: configuration, openssh

I am setting up a Debian server through DigitalOcean, which I initialized with a SSH-key. Currently I can log onto the server as root or as a user.

Normally when I do this type of configuration, I uncomment `PermitRootLogin yes` from `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and change it to `PermitRootLogin no`. This time, however, I saw a shorter `ssh_config` that contained no `PermitRootLogin`.

When I tried to add it in, vim's syntax highlighting didn't recognize it, and restarting `sshd` didn't have any effect. I looked at the man page for `ssh_config` and the keyword wasn't listed.

How do I prohibit logging in as root via SSH?

Comment: ssh**d**_config, for the server, not ssh_config for the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ssh_config` file is the default configuration for SSH clients. The server configuration will be found in `sshd_config`.  The `PermitRootLogin` is a server setting (it modifies the behaviour of the SSH server) that should go in the server configuration file.